# filter javascript array on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an input box that filters an array and only shows those matches.

```
let songs = [
   {name: 'Let It Be', artist: 'The Beatles},
   {name: 'Lady Madonna', artist: 'The Beatles },
   {name: 'Mama Mia', artist: 'The Beatles}
];
```

In the following example it will just match by name.

```
let value = 'name';
let q = 'Let it be' // value entered in input box;

let songFilter = songs.filter(function(song) {
   return song[value].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q) != -1; // returns true or false
});
```

Then when I enter `Let It Be` into the input box it will show return just `'Let It Be'`. However, I want to filter by two songs, so if I enter `Let It Be, Lady Madonna` I would like it to return two songs.

I have taken many approaches but cannot figure out how to get this working. I also have `lodash` available if this makes it easier to solve.

Comment: `split` `q` into an array of names and then inside `filter` use `some`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `Array#filter` and `Array#find`

```js
let songs = [
   {name: 'Let It Be', artist: 'The Beatles'},
   {name: 'Lady Madonna', artist: 'The Beatles' },
   {name: 'Mama Mia', artist: 'The Beatles'}
];
let value = 'name';
let q = 'Let it be,Lady Madonna' // value entered in input box;
let splitQ = q.split(',').map(sq=>sq.toLowerCase());

let songFilter = songs.filter(s=>splitQ.find(sq=>s[value].toLowerCase().indexOf(sq) > -1 ) !== undefined );

console.log(songFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let songFilter = songs.filter(function(song) {
    ['let it be', 'lady madonna'].indexOf(song[value].toString().toLowerCase()) > -1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Set` to key the entries (after `split`) that have been input. That way you can see in constant time whether there is a match. Here that `Set` is passed to `filter` as the context, so it can be referenced with `this`:

```js
let songs = [
   {name: 'Let It Be', artist: 'The Beatles' },
   {name: 'Lady Madonna', artist: 'The Beatles' },
   {name: 'Mama Mia', artist: 'The Beatles' }
];

function find(byKey, valueCsv) {
    return songs.filter(function(song) {
       return this.has(song[byKey].toLowerCase())
    }, new Set(valueCsv.trim().toLowerCase().split(/\s*,\s*/)));
}

songInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
    matches.textContent = JSON.stringify(find('name', songInput.value), null, 2);
});
```

```html
Type song name(s):<input id="songInput" style="width:100%">
<pre id="matches"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment above:

```js
let songs = [
   {name: 'Let It Be', artist: 'The Beatles'},
   {name: 'Lady Madonna', artist: 'The Beatles'},
   {name: 'Mama Mia', artist: 'The Beatles'}
];

let value = 'name';
let q = 'Let it be, Lady madonna';

// First: split the q value into multiple songs (and make them lowercased)
let qSongs = q.split(', ').map(e => e.toLowerCase());

// Second: filter song that are in the above resultant array (qSongs)
// for each song in the songs array
let songFilter = songs.filter(song => 
  // see if there is some qsong in the qSongs array such that the value of song is equal to qsong
  qSongs.some(qsong => 
    song[value].toLowerCase().indexOf(qsong) != -1
  )
);
    
console.log(songFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let songs = [
  { name: 'Let It Be', artist: 'The Beatles' },
  { name: 'Lady Madonna', artist: 'The Beatles' },
  { name: 'Mama Mia', artist: 'The Beatles' }
];

let value = 'name';
let q = 'Let it be, Lady madonna';

let songFilter = _.filter(songs, (song) => {
  let regex = new RegExp(q.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, '|'), 'gi');
  return regex.test(song[value]);
});

console.log(songFilter);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```